# Pustyl’nikov’s equivalent criteria for RH

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

In this paper (Pustyl’snikov 1999 *Russ. Math. Surv.* **54** 262), Pustyl’nikov proved the following two theorems

**Theorem 1**
*All the even derivative of $\xi(s) $ at point $s=1/2$ are strictly positive.*

**Theorem 2**
*If at least one of those even derivatives were not positive, then RH would be false: in this case there would exist a complex zero $s_1$ ( and it’s mirror image $1-s_1$) that does not lie on the line $\mathrm{Re}(s)$=1/2.*

As you can see that this is similar to Li’s criteria.

**Question**
What is the gap between these two theorems and a proof of RH?

Comment: What do you mean by "gap"? Do you mean, why don't they imply RH logically? Or, what ideas must be added to give a proof of RH?

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying! I mean why don’t they imply RH logically? Because I was not able to see any gap. One possibility might be that an equivalent of theorem 2 above only works for even order polynomials.

Comment: This may seem naive, but... Theorem 2 is stated as a one-way implication.  How can any statement of the form “if X then Y is false” be used to prove that Y is true?  Seems to me that Theorem 1 only serves to make Theorem 2 vacuous (which rhymes with part of reuns’s answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 1 is trivial
$$\xi^{(2n)}(1/2) = 2^{2-2n}\int_1^\infty f(x)(\log x)^{2n}dx$$
with $f(x)= x^{1/4} \sum_{n\ge 1}\pi n^2 e^{-\pi n^2 x}(x\pi n^2-\frac32 )
\ge 0$ on $[1,\infty)$

So the theorem 2 doesn't mean anything. When replacing $\zeta(s)$ by the Dirichlet L-function of a quadratic character we'll get that $\xi_\chi$ has similar properties except that $\xi_\chi(1)=0$ so its derivatives can't be all $\ge 0$, therefore I hardly see what the theorem 2 means.

Comment: @rerun thanks a lot for the answer! Now I remembered that I saw something like $\xi(s)=\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{b_{2n}}{(2n)!}(s-\tfrac12)^{2n}$. And $b_{2n}>0$.

Comment: The $(-1)^n$ is for $\Xi$

Comment: @rerun please take a look at my expanded comment in the answer section.

Comment: Yes it seems a valid interpretation of "theorem 2", for $L(s,\chi)$ we'll look at $\prod_\beta (1-\frac{s^2}{(\beta-1/2)^2})$ if the RH is true then it is $=\sum_{k\ge 0} c_k s^{2k}$ with $c_k>0$.

Comment: The $\geq0$ bound for $f$ on $[1,\infty)$ can easily be replaced by $>0$.

Comment: @rerun the alternating sign seems to be a necessary condition but not sufficient.

Comment: @mike   the RH equivalent that is most accessible is that of Nicolas, http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/petitsphiDPP.pdf  ++++  https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3613  That of his student Robin became better known, however primorials are less work to calculate than colossally abundant numbers

Comment: Thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. It just allows me to easily expand my comment because I am typing this on a tiny cell phone screen.
I tested two polynomials (even in z) to see if the coefficients are alternating in sign.
$$f(z)=(z^2-1)(z^2-4)(z^2-9)(z^2-25)$$
$$=z^8-39z^6+399z^4-1261z^2+900\tag{1}$$
$$g(z)=(z^2-4)(z^2-9)(z-(1+3i))(z-(1-3i))(z+(1+3i))(z+(1-3i))$$
$$=z^8+3z^6-72z^4-724^2+3600\tag{2}$$.

I do see the sign pattern that Pustyl’nikov implied in his theorem 2 ( and I guessed).
**Update**
I did find a counter example to theorem 2.
$$ h(z)=(z^2-4)(z^2-9)(z-(3+i))(z-(3-i))(z+(3+i))(z-(3-i))$$
$$=z^8-29z^6+344z^4-1876z^2+3600\tag{3}$$.
The sign pattern is alternating.